# heroku python buildpack pip install not adding the entry-points.txt file when installing

Tags: django, heroku, pip, heroku-cli

My runtime is `python-3.7.5`

I have an Django reusable app with an entry point in `setup.py` defined as:

```
setup = (
...
entry_points={'my.group': 'foo = bar'},
)
```

That allows me to use `pkg_resources.iter_entry_points(group="my.group", name=None)` to get a list of plugins.

I didn't know that until I had this bug, but it seems to rely on a `entry_points.txt` file that gets installed in the `egg-info`.

This `entry_points.txt` file seems to be missing when I push to heroku. I did a `heroku run bash` and:

```
~/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/m_package.egg-info $ ls
dependency_links.txt  installed-files.txt  PKG-INFO  SOURCES.txt  top_level.txt
```

but when I uninstall it and install it manually, and I recheck:

```
~/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/my_package.egg-info $ ls
dependency_links.txt  entry_points.txt  installed-files.txt  PKG-INFO  requires.txt  SOURCES.txt  top_level.txt
```

Am I missing something that the buildpack does?

The only extra thing to add is that I'm using https://github.com/timshadel/heroku-buildpack-github-netrc.git to get Https authentication in git, (my requirements.txt has some packages from private github repos) but I don't think that this should matter at all.

Comment: I thought it might be the pip version so I forked the heroku python buildpack and tried updating pip but that did not do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

After messing with the official django buildpack, I realized it's just caching the packages, and since I updated `my_package`'s code but not its version, it was not picking up the new library, hence no entry points. When I was doing `pip install` by hand on the heroku instance, it was picking the right library.

Good to know anyway, so keeping the question and the answer if anyone has the same problem one day.